# Woo Commerce API - problem with the image

Tags: php, url, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to add images using the Woo Commerce API, but I am getting an error:

> "A valid URL was not provided. [woocommerce_product_image_upload_error]"

My link has got the port on the address... is that the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Woocommerce API validates URLs using the [wp_http_validate_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_http_validate_url/) method.

Among other things, it does check for the port number in the URL and only allows ports 80, 443 and 8080.

You can change the allowed ports using the [http_allowed_safe_ports](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/http_allowed_safe_ports/) filter.

Here's an example snippet you can use for changing the allowed ports:

```
add_filter("http_allowed_safe_ports", "custom_allowed_ports");

function custom_allowed_ports($ports){

    $ports = [80, 443, 8080, 3000];

    return $ports;
}
```

Comment: The [`http_allowed_safe_ports`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/http_allowed_safe_ports/) filter can be used to change those though.

Comment: @CBroe You're right, I edited my answer to incorporate it.

Comment: _Slight_ improvement suggestion: It probably won't matter much in this instance, but if any other plugin had already manipulated this list (because it also needs to make requests to a custom port), we'd be overwriting that with this code. Better to just _add_ the custom port to the already existing list - `$ports[] = 3000;` (And then `array_unique` could be applied as well, to avoid "duplicates" - but I don't think those would hurt either, it is probably satisfied as soon as it finds the first match in the list.)

Comment: I used this option "reject_unsafe_urls" and it works. thank you!

Comment: Your workaround works fine. Thanks.
I have insert the code in this file: "wp-includes/functions.php"
But after an update of Wordpress i have lost the modification.

Have i made a mistake?
Where do i have to insert the code? In another file?
Thanks

Comment: @MarcoAvo98 The most ideal spot would be in your CHILD themes functions.php file. Most popular themes come with their own child themes, but if your theme doesn't come with a child theme you can create one yourself with this guide from the official WordPress Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/